# merge two csv files according to matching rows and add new columns in linux

Tags: linux, unix

I am developing an application using java, but for that I need a csv file in some order. I dont know linux much, but wondering if some way is there to merge the csv files in the required format.

I have two csv files containing hundreds of thousands of records. a sample is below:

```
name,Direction,Date
abc,sent,Jan 21 2014 02:06 
xyz,sent,Nov 21 2014 01:09
pqr,sent,Oct 21 2014 03:06
```

and

```
name,Direction,Date
abc,received,Jan 22 2014 02:06
xyz,received,Nov 22 2014 02:06
```

so, this second csv file would contain some records of file 1. What I need is a new csv like this:

```
name,Direction,Date,currentDirection,receivedDate
abc,sent,Jan 21 2014 02:06,received,Jan 22 2014 02:06
xyz,sent,Nov 21 2014 01:09,received,Nov 22 2014 02:06
pqr,sent,Oct 21 2014 03:06
```

Need to add the columns(4th and 5th column) according to the matching data in column1. if no matching data is there in the second file, the columns should be empty like above.

so is there a bash command in linux to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

awk may work for you:

```
kent$  awk -F, -v OFS="," 
       'BEGIN{print "name,Direction,Date,currentDirection,receivedDate"}
        NR==FNR&&NR>1{a[$1]=$0;next}
        FNR>1{printf "%s%s\n",$0,($1 in a?FS a[$1]:"")}' 2.csv 1.csv
name,Direction,Date,currentDirection,receivedDate
abc,sent,Jan 21 2014 02:06,abc,received,Jan 22 2014 02:06
xyz,sent,Nov 21 2014 01:09,xyz,received,Nov 22 2014 02:06
pqr,sent,Oct 21 2014 03:06
```

### update

```
kent$  awk -F, -v OFS="," 'BEGIN{print "name,Direction,Date,currentDirection,receivedDate"}
        NR==FNR&&NR>1{a[$1]=$2 FS $3;next}
        FNR>1{printf "%s%s\n",$0,($1 in a?FS a[$1]:"")}' 2.csv 1.csv 
name,Direction,Date,currentDirection,receivedDate
abc,sent,Jan 21 2014 02:06,received,Jan 22 2014 02:06
xyz,sent,Nov 21 2014 01:09,received,Nov 22 2014 02:06
pqr,sent,Oct 21 2014 03:06
```

Comment: kent - its not working as expected. Output is below:  name,Direction,Date,currentDirection,receivedDate
abc,sent,Jan 21 2014 02:06 ,abc,received,Jan 22 2014 02:06

Comment: first column is getting repeated and the columns are also not arranged in the required format.

Comment: @user3884944 it worked here (as shown in the answer) with your test files. perhaps you have different awk version?

Comment: In your answer you would see that name is getting repeated two times e.g. abc is coming two times. what I need name should not be repeated.... it must be  **abc,sent,jan 21 2014,received, jan 22 2014**

Comment: Plus, in currentdirection column - name is coming, in receiveddate  column "received" is appended and Last received date does not have a column name at all :(

Comment: @ani0710 ok, I see, didn't check your output carefully, my fault, I update the answer soon

Answer (score 3):

You can use this `join` command to accomplish this.  The first file is `1.csv` and the second file is `2.csv`

```
join -1 1 -2 1 -t, -a 1  1.csv 2.csv | sed "s/Direction,Date/currentDirection,receivedDate/2"
```

Output:

```
name,Direction,Date,currentDirection,receivedDate
abc,sent,Jan 21 2014 02:06,received,Jan 22 2014 02:06
xyz,sent,Nov 21 2014 01:09,received,Nov 22 2014 02:06
pqr,sent,Oct 21 2014 03:06
```

Explanation:

You want to join on the first field in both files, therefore `-1 1 -2 1`

You want to use comma, therefore `-t,`

You want to display all unmatched records in file 1, therefore `-a 1`, you could also append `-a 2` if needed.

The /2 in the sed command tells `sed` to replace the 2nd occurrence

Comment: Great, its working perfectly ! but what I need is, different names for columns 4 and 5. Can you please modify your command according to this need?

Comment: can u explain further on, what -a 2 would do if I use that? I got that, -a 1 is for displaying all unmatched records in file 1. So what -a 2 would do? will it display all the records of file 2? then what about file 1 records?

Comment: this is what -a does: print unpairable lines coming from file FILENUM, where FILENUM is 1 or 2, corresponding to FILE1 or FILE2

Comment: Run `join --help` for more options.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Your given command is short and more easy to understand :)